# Mediascanner is not working

Tags: custom-roms, root-access, media-scanner

Currently I am using a Samsung galaxy note-2 with custom ROM (slimkat 4.4.2.built 4 official).

Since the last few days my media scanner is not working properly for some time.
Sometimes after restarting it works fine, but not always.

I already tried few media scanner apps from Google Play Store
but when I run those apps, they crash.

It scans only my phone content not my SD-card, while using phone browser
I can access the card contents. But my gallery and music players are not able to scan SD card media.

Does anybody have a solution for that? Or do I have to wait for slimkat net update?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What steps do you take, what do you expect to happen, and what does happen?

Comment: Actually it's just scanning my phone data not my sdcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can often be caused by filesystem corruption on the SD card. The SD card might appear to work normally if you don't access the corrupted parts of the filesystem, but since the media scanner reads the whole filesystem, it's much more likely to get stuck on a corrupted file or directory.

Try removing the SD card and using a card reader on your PC to check the filesystem (e.g. with scandisk or fsck).